# Oracle trouble in getting data from a partitioned table

Tags: oracle, plsql, partitioning

On a new job I have to figure out how some database reporting scripts are working.
There is one table that is giving me some trouble. I see in existing scripts that it is a partitioned table.
My problem is that whatever query I run on this table returns me "no rows selected".

Here are some details about my investigation in this table:

**Table size estimate**

```
SQL> select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 Megabytes from dba_segments where segment_name = 'PPREC';

MEGABYTES
----------
45.625
```

**Partitions**

There are a total of 730 partitions on date range.

```
SQL> select min(PARTITION_NAME),max(PARTITION_NAME) from dba_segments where segment_name = 'PPREC';

MIN(PARTITION_NAME)            MAX(PARTITION_NAME)
------------------------------ ------------------------------
PART20110201                   PART20130130
```

There are several tablespaces and partitions are allocated in them

```
SQL> select tablespace_name, count(partition_name) from dba_segments where segment_name = 'PPREC' group by tablespace_name;

TABLESPACE_NAME                COUNT(PARTITION_NAME)
------------------------------ ---------------------
REC_DATA_01                                       281
REC_DATA_02                                        48
REC_DATA_03                                        70
REC_DATA_04                                        26
REC_DATA_05                                        44
REC_DATA_06                                        51
REC_DATA_07                                        13
REC_DATA_08                                        48
REC_DATA_09                                        32
REC_DATA_10                                        52
REC_DATA_11                                        35
REC_DATA_12                                        30
```

Additional query:

```
SQL> select * from dba_segments where segment_name='PPREC' and partition_name='PART20120912';

OWNER SEGMENT_NAME PARTITION_NAME SEGMENT_TYPE    TABLESPACE_NAME HEADER_FILE HEADER_BLOCK BYTES BLOCKS EXTENTS 
----- ------------ -------------- --------------- --------------- ----------- ------------ ----- ------ -------
HIST  PPREC        PART20120912   TABLE PARTITION REC_DATA_01              13       475315 65536      8       1

INITIAL_EXTENT NEXT_EXTENT MIN_EXTENTS MAX_EXTENTS PCT_INCREASE FREELISTS FREELIST_GROUPS RELATIVE_FNO BUFFER_POOL
-------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------ --------- --------------- ------------ -----------
  65536                              1  2147483645                                                 13    DEFAULT
```

**Tabespace usage**

Here is a space summary (composite of dba_tablespaces, dba_data_files, dba_segments, dba_free_space)

```
TABLESPACE_NAME                TOTAL_MEGABYTES USED_MEGABYTES FREE_MEGABYTES
------------------------------ --------------- -------------- --------------
REC_01_INDX                              30,700            250         30,449
REC_02_INDX                               7,745              7          7,737
REC_03_INDX                              22,692             15         22,677
REC_04_INDX                              15,768             10         15,758
REC_05_INDX                              25,884             16         25,868
REC_06_INDX                              27,992             16         27,975
REC_07_INDX                              17,600             10         17,590
REC_08_INDX                              18,864             11         18,853
REC_09_INDX                              19,700             12         19,687
REC_10_INDX                              28,716             16         28,699
REC_DATA_01                             102,718            561        102,156
REC_DATA_02                              24,544          3,140         21,403
REC_DATA_03                              72,710              4         72,704
REC_DATA_04                              29,191              2         29,188
REC_DATA_05                              42,696              3         42,692
REC_DATA_06                              52,780            323         52,456
REC_DATA_07                              16,536              1         16,534
REC_DATA_08                              49,247              3         49,243
REC_DATA_09                              30,848              2         30,845
REC_DATA_10                              49,620              3         49,616
REC_DATA_11                              40,616              2         40,613
REC_DATA_12                             184,922        123,435         61,486
```

The tablespace usage seems to confirm that this table is not empty, in fact its last tablespace (REC_DATA_12) seems pretty busy.

**Existing scripts**

What I find puzzling is that there are some PL/SQL stored procedures that seem to work on that table and get data out of it.
An example of such a stored procedure is as follows:

```
procedure FIRST_REC as
vpartition varchar2(12);
begin
select 'PART'||To_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') INTO vpartition FROM DUAL;

execute immediate
'MERGE INTO FIRST_REC_temp a
 USING (SELECT bno, min(trdate) mintr,max(trdate) maxtr
        FROM PPREC PARTITION ('||vpartition||') WHERE route_id IS NOT NULL AND trunc(trdate) <= trunc(sysdate-1)
        GROUP BY bno) b
    ON (a.bno=b.bno)
    when matched then
    update set a.last_tr = b.maxtr
    when not matched then
    insert (a.bno,a.last_tr,a.first_tr)
    values (b.bno,b.maxtr,b.mintr)';
    commit;
```

However if I try using the same syntax manually on the table, here is what I get:

```
SQL> select count(*) from PPREC PARTITION (PART20120912);

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

I have tried a few random partitions and I always get the same 0 count.

**Summary**
- I see a table that seems to contain data (space used, tablespaces, data files)
- The table is partitioned (one partition per day over a period of 730 days ending end of January 2013)
- Scripts are extracting data from that table somehow

**Question**
- My queries using PARTITION are all returning me "no rows selected". What am I doing wrong? How could I find out how to extract data from this table?

Comment: Space used is not a good indicator that there are rows. Data may be deleted. How are you sure that merge really transport data to table FIRST_REC_temp? Are you sure that PPREC is the same table as in procedure? You may be in another schema/instance.

Comment: What you see if `select * from dba_segments where segment_name = 'PPREC' and partition_name = 'PART20120912'?     Another point is that you should not qurery a partioned table using partition clause but using where clause(should be transparent for programmer what partitions exists).

Comment: Indeed, data could have been deleted. This is what I am trying to figure out, as I remain convinced that there is some data in there. I have checked it is indeed the right schema.

Comment: Thanks Florin for the comment, I have edited my question to include the query you mentioned. I realize that the optimiser should take care of the partitioning, however it doesn't seem to work properly and I see scripts using PARTITION some I was assuming that it was required, for some reason.

Comment: You have only one extent allocated in that partition, the initial extent. Probably you've never inserted something in that partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's possible that some other process might be deleting the data, but without visiting your site there's no way for anyone here to tell if that might be so.

I don't see in your post that you mentioned the name of the partitioning DATE column, but based on the SQL you posted I'll assume it's TRDATE - if this is not correct, change TRDATE in the statement below to be the partitioning column.

That said, give this a try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM PPREC
  WHERE TRDATE >= TO_DATE('01-SEP-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

This assumes you should have data in this table from September.  If you find data, great.  If you don't - well, Back In The Day (when men were men, women were women, and computers were water-cooled :-) we had a little saying about memory on IBM mainframes:

```
1.  If you can see it,   and it's there,     it's Real.
2.  If you can't see it, but it's there,     it's Protected.
3.  If you can see it,   but it's not there, it's Virtual.
4.  If you can't see it, and it's not there, it's GONE!
```

:-)

Use of the PARTITION clause should be reserved for situations where you are experiencing a performance problem (note: guessing about what is or is not going to be a performance problem is not allowed.  Until you've got a performance problem you don't have a performance problem.  Over the years I've found that software spends a lot of execution time in the darndest places :-), and the usual fixes (adding indexes, deleting unnecessary data, human sacrifice, etc) haven't worked.  Basically, write your queries normally and trust the database to get it right.  (In the general case - *always* write the simplest code - and do the simplest thing - that could possibly work.  99+ percent of the time it will be fine.  That allows you to spend your optimization time on the less-than-one-percent cases where simple isn't good enough - and *most* of the software you write or design will be simple and easy to understand).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Yes the partition is done on PRDATE. I'm starting to wonder if indeed there is any data there. Seeing nightly scripts being executed, which can extract data from there, make me believe it's not "GONE" yet :) [great quote, btw]

Comment: The count with the TRDATE clause returns 0 again.

Comment: OK - change TRDATE to PRDATE and see what you get.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Partition is done on TRDATE and so is the query.

Comment: OK, then - run this: `SELECT * FROM PPREC`.  Do you get any results?

Comment: No results. I know, it looks bad. The data is probably gone. But then why nightly scripts can extract data from this table? I must be missing something.

Comment: OK, the data has been deleted.  My best guess is that somewhere in the scripts which run every night there is a process which deletes the data.  You'll have to go through them, searching for operations on the PPREC table - somewhere there's either a DELETE, or a TRUNCATE TABLE, or the partition is dropped and then re-added, or something similar I can't think of at the moment.  But somehow the data is being removed.

Comment: Thanks Bob, appreciate your input. Will dig more into it.